# JM(joint model) package of R software error message

Tags: r, model

I received a error message below when I tried to implement Joint Model by using  JM  package of R software.

"Error in if (t1 || t2) { : missing value where TRUE / FALSE needed"

I'm not familiar with R software.
If you have an idea how to address the problem ,please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with NAs/ missing values. You could check if there are NAs in your input data and test if it works if you replace/remove them.

Comment: if (t1 || t2)  - when both t1 and t2 are NA, then this if clause will give the said error. But as I understood it this is anyway just an error message from within the package. So you have to fix your inputs to the package.